# Any way to avoid an exception for phrase query on positionless field in Solr 4.x

Tags: solr

I didn't have this problem before 4.x upgrade. The problem is that I have a field whose omitTermFreqAndPositions attribute is set to true for various reasons. When a user performs phrase query explicitly or implicitly, it failed silently in Solr 3.5 or 3.6 but not in 4.x.

What would be a way to avoid this? One obvious way to reset omitTermFreqAndPositions to false but that's something I would like to avoid. I heard about implementing some kind of custom similarity class for this particular field but I would like to understand it better (so any explanation about it would be great whether it can be a solution for my problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own [requestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRequestHandler), where there you will catch this exception and ignore it silently. See [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity#Write_Your_Own_RequestHandler_or_SearchComponent)